# Validate Comma Separated values as Azure DevOps Parameters

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am creating an Azure DevOps Pipeline.

User will be asked to fill a mandatory parameter before pipeline run. This parameter must be Comma separated string.
Is there any feature Out of Box to CHECK if input string is comma separated or not?

OR do you suggest let this parameter be accepted and then run a job/ task say powershell task to check the pattern of this input and accordingly move forward?

Comment: There is not an out of the box functionality to check a comma separated string. You should make this check using a powershell.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such validation out of the box so as yo said you need to add a script to validate it.

For example:

```
$param = "${{ parameters.test }}"
$reg = [regex]'^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,50},[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,50}$'
if($param -match $reg)
{
   Write-Host "The param is good!"
}
else
{
   Write-Error "The param is not a comma separated string"
}
```